# Unable to get dynamically created HTML inside a div

Tags: jquery, angular, modal-dialog

I have a component file in which am calling another component file. Like

```
this.dialog.open(ProqrComponent, {
        width: '560px',
        height: 'auto',
        panelClass : 'docqr'
});
```

Where ProqrComponent is a different component file. In ProqrComponent this is how am handling this :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

var scope = this;
this.cc=document.getElementById("mcanvas");
var ctx = this.cc.getContext("2d");
this.img = document.getElementById("scream");
this.gctx = ctx;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 520,140);
ctx.drawImage(this.img,0,20,520, 140);
this.qrcode =  $("#qrcode div img").attr("src");
console.log(this.qrcode);
}
```

Well, am using canvas. So this drawImage method will produce below HTML and append to dialog HTML dynamically.

```
<div id="qrcode">
  <div>
    <img src="image/...." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I can't change this `qrcode` HTML.

But this `console.log(this.qrcode);` always console `undefined`. Any help how to get image src in the angular dialog. Thanx in advance.

Comment: what do you get when you do console.log($("#qrcode div img")) ?

Comment: Console giving undefined as said by user.

Comment: I am getting `undefined` while doing the console. @AIqbal

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the src attribute wo an variable like:

```
<img [src]="imageSource" />
```

And in Your component:

```
imageSource:string = "image/..."
```

Then you can assign this variable to the qr code:

```
this.qrcode =  this.imageSource;
```

Comment: In canvas drawing we dnt have access to dynamically created HTML. So dnt gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the image content from the canvas to draw in the dialog, you should get the image binary data from the canvas as base64 and use it to draw.

This is the fragment that extracts the base64 data:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let image = document.getElementById('source');

ctx.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
ctx.fillRect(30,10,10,10);
const data = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Please see the example bellow: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-image-from-canvas?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdraw%2Fdraw.component.ts